# Make link to Application folder

Tags: macos

Sublime Text editor has in DMG file link to Applications dir (blue icons with arrow). It has small size.

How to make such link on my own folder? It must work in all Macs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the terminal, use `cd` to open the folder where you want to create the symbolic link (this is how that kind of link is called, in case you want to research a bit more about it). Example:

```
cd /Users/MyUser/Desktop/
```

**Note:** In case the path has spaces, write it with backslashes before each space, like that:

```
cd /Users/MyUser/Desktop/My\ Folder/
```

Then, use that command to create it:

```
ln -s /Applications/ Applications
```

It will create a symbolic link which opens the path `/Applications/`, which means that it will work in any macOS computer.

Reference:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115648